# Why do I have so much increase in reputation all of a sudden?

Tags: support, reputation

(I have no idea where to post this, so if it’s off topic or anything, please let me know where to post it)

So I posted a hand-made riddle on Puzzling yesterday (for which I got 20 upvotes:)).

Anyways, today, I come back to see a very increased amount of reputation on **ALL** of my stack exchange accounts.

For example, [image: ELU] in this picture, you can see the (very fast) increased amount of reputation, even though I have only 3 questions (one with -1).
[image: Interpersonal] here is the same thing...

So is it because one of my questions on a different stack exchange site that increase my reputation on all of my accounts, or is it a bug?

Comment: Perhaps it's because some people clicked on your name in admiration of your puzzle, and they looked at some of your posts on other SEs that are linked from your network profile, and they voted for some of those posts that they liked?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the [**Association Bonus,**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/) which is given to all your associated accounts when you reach 200 points on one of them. You can get to your reputation changes from your user profile page: click on your username in the header bar, and then on *Reputation* in the line under the two panels, where *Summary* is highlighted on the left.

[image: Screen shot of association bonus]

Comment: I'm still puzzled by this @Andrew. I've had a sudden increase of about 5,000 on my EL & U a/c and about 2,000 on Politics. Nothing appears in the reputation column which explains this. I'm not complaining - just curious??

Comment: Have you seen the announcement about questions all being recalculated to be 10 points per upvote instead of five? There's a banner above the header on every site to a post on https://stackoverflow.blog.

Comment: Ah! Ok- thankyou!